Versioned Transaction
I've ran into problem, that there aren't any examples of Version Transactions in Solana_sdk.rs. The thing is, the key which successfully signs legacy transaction, cant sign V0.
let transaction = VersionedTransaction::try_new(message, &[&key]).expect("Failed to create transaction");


Failed to create transaction: KeypairPubkeyMismatch
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.

Can somebody help me with that please?

You'll need to provide some more information unfortunately, KeypairPubkeyMismatch usually means that one of the required signing keys isn't provided, or that you've provided a keypair that isn't declared as a signer in the transaction.

I've fixed the problem. My signer wasnt at 0 index in accounts vector. Also, anybody knows, why ALT lookups in rust are so complicated, comparing to web3-solana? Managing 40 indexes was brutal... Maybe there are some libs, which help to manage it?

There might be, but I'm not aware of them unfortunately -- open source contributions to the Rust libraries are always appreciated though!
